# WPF usercontrol as a factory

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a situation where I load several usercontrols dynamically. Since all of them inherit from `UserControl`, I was wondering if it made sense to make UserControl a Factory and return the appropriate usercontrol based on some condition.

Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean whether you can create a UserControlFactory which I believe is fine because at the end of day any control is a class any way and if you need create instances dynamically then you can create a factory for them.

But first see if you can accomplish the same thing with DataTemplate, Trigger, or DataTemplateSelector

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx